# IOS 10 Control Center volume linked to Gas Buddy on iPhone

Tags: ios

[image]

If I uninstall Gas Buddy, it returns to Music. But as soon as I reinstall Gas Buddy...yup, reverts back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound control in Control Centre gives either the currently playing source of sound *or* the most recent source of sound. I'm assuming Gas Buddy had some kind of background sound going on. If you start to play music through the Music app, Control Centre should list Music as the app.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I had no music on my iPhone, downloaded a few songs, played one and now the volume control shows Music.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of assistance. The Control Centre also works with other sound things (if you play music with Soundcloud, for example, the controls will show up there).